# How is oxygen and carbon dioxide exchange mediated by hemoglobin?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, physiology, hematology

Oxygen is transferred by hemoglobin from the lungs to tissues, while carbon dioxide is transferred by hemoglobin from tissues to lungs. How is this regulated bidirectional transfer mediated?

Answer (score 2):

Under conditions of high CO<sub>2</sub> (in tissues such as muscle) and hence high acidity hemoglobin binds preferentially CO<sub>2</sub>, thereby mediating CO<sub>2</sub> removal. Under conditions of low CO<sub>2</sub> (high pH) and high O<sub>2</sub> (conditions met in the lungs), it preferably binds O<sub>2</sub>, thereby releasing CO<sub>2</sub>. Hence, the specific characteristics of hemoglobin allow for CO<sub>2</sub> uptake in the body, and O<sub>2</sub> uptake and CO<sub>2</sub> release in the lungs. Info from [wikipedia on hemoglobin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemoglobin)

Comment: please explain more.and the primary purpose is mechanism of exchanging O2 and CO2.mostly from biochemistry pointview.

Comment: @Majid have you done any research on your own? Did you read the Wikipedia article and those linked to it? Your questions are quite broad.